# Body not taking the full screen width

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with a webpage, the body is not taking the entire screen width.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see, the right side of the screen has a "blue gap"
I checked the viewport, "reseted" the html, added a 100% width 0 margin, etc... but still doesn't work. Any ideas? I don't even know what could it be.

This is what i have in one of the CSS files

```
body{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:1.42857143;
    color:#333;
    background-color:#fff; 
    margin:0; 
    border:none; 
    padding:0;
}
```

This is in another CSS used for the site

```
body{
   margin:0; 
   padding:0; 
   border:none;
}
```

Also I the same values (margin, padding and border in 0 and none) in a  tag in the head. :(

Comment: Instead of posting the head, you'll need to post the **CSS** affecting the **`<body>`** section. You may want to ensure that you have a 'clear' starting point with `margin: 0`, `border: none`, and possibly even `padding: 0`.

Comment: you're going to have to show a lot more code if you expect to get anything more than guesses about what your problem is

Comment: Perhaps not related to the issue, but can you really just declare some of your HTML element attributes with surrounding them in quotes. For example, I always thought you'd have to write `<link href="/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />`

Comment: @ObsidianAge i have updated the question

Comment: @PacoMeraz, please post the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it -- people aren't going to want to type out your code manually! ;) Can you please update your question again so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can reproduce the problem with ease, and therefor help you solve it faster :)

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
body {
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```css
body { 
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  This is a test.
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanna  suggest you to always use Universal Selector(*) to reset the padding and margin of all tags to 0. Don't make your code complicated and tangled. Try to write the code as

```css
*{
 padding : 0;
 margin : 0;
 }
html{
 width:100%;
 height:900px; /* height depends on you're requirement*/
 }
body{
 width:100%;
 height:600px; /* height depends on you're requirement*/
 background:#999;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Full Size Body Width </title>
</head>
<body>
   Demo Webpage.
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help you.